Can I write a program to count the number of vowels using string.includes() and for of loop?
I have tried passing strings to the getCount function that contain 'aeiou' and not but the value of vowelsCount is always 0.
I tried using string includes() function using the documentation, but it always returns count as 0, I have the code with which we can get the exact number of vowels in a string, but I prefer to use the approach taught by MDN docs.
This is the approach i prefered:
const vowelCount = str => {
 
let voweslCount = 0;

for ( let char of str){

if (str.includes('aeiou'))

voweslCount++;

}

return voweslCount;

}


Two very obvious problems: 1. that's not how includes works (it's looking for a whole substring, not any individual character); and 2. you repeatedly apply it to str (ignoring the individual char entirely). "aeiou".includes(char), perhaps? I'd strongly recommend doing some basic debugging with e.g. https://pythontutor.com/javascript.html.

Hi, unless this is an exercise, you may want to look at String.prototype.match() - JavaScript | MDN.

You can also start by creating an array containing each letter of the string, then transform each letter of that array into an array with map()


function countVowels(str){
  let counter = 0
  let arrayOfStr = Array.from(str.toLowerCase())
  let arrayOfArray = arrayOfStr.map(elem=>[elem])
  for(let i=0;i<arrayOfArray.length;i++) {
    if(arrayOfArray[i].includes('a') || arrayOfArray[i].includes('e') || arrayOfArray[i].includes('i') || arrayOfArray[i].includes('o') || arrayOfArray[i].includes('u') || arrayOfArray[i].includes('y')){
      counter+=1
    }
  }
  return (counter) 
}



console.log(countVowels('Hello World'))

/* you can also loop through arrayOfArray with forEach as below*/

function countVowels2(str){
  let counter = 0
  let arrayOfStr = Array.from(str.toLowerCase())
  let arrayOfArray = arrayOfStr.map(elem=>[elem])
  arrayOfArray.forEach((elem)=>{
    if(elem.includes('a') || elem.includes('e') || elem.includes('i') || elem.includes('o') || elem.includes('u') || elem.includes('y')){
      counter+=1
    }
  })
  return counter
}

console.log(countVowels2('Hello World'))



function. Then check with includes() if each array containing letters includes vowels
